# Can't access cluster targeted data soucre jta-source from EJB in cluster

Tags: ejb, weblogic, cluster-computing

I have EJB packaged jar deployed in a cluster.  When I try to create an entity manager with the entitymanager factory I get a namingexception because it can't find my jndi data source (jdbc/oracledb). If I update the datasource to target add the adminserver, I don't get the error it it find the datasource.  I am new to EJB and clustering.  I am able to see the jndi tree in my cluster from within the Weblogic Admin console and I can programmatically  find jdbc/oracledb when I do lookup in my cluster.  My entire application is deployed to the cluster, so I don't know why any of it should be within the context of the admin server.  I'm wondering if this is a class loading issues.  Thanks for any help.